# mysqli_connect() connection error on webserver

Tags: jquery, database, connection

I am using $connecDB = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password,$db_name)or die('could not connect to database');  for my page but after using correct user pass its showing 'could not connect to database' on my webserver but its working on localhost! please suggest me what could be the error?

Comment: It is working when I am using the same code with localhost,root,''; but only on my hosting server its showing could not connect to database

Answer (score 0):

Are you using localhost as well on your webserver? If your database is hosted on the same webserver use localhost.

Comment: yes I am using localhost as $db_host. or shall i pur my domain url?

Comment: you should use localhost if the database is the same server as the webserver. Check username, password and permission. Have a look at the logs as well. What platform is this?

Comment: Oh! it was space in my db name, now its working. Thank you so much